# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created:

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to invoke the chrome browser using testng, maven but code is giving below error.

```
"org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: 
Could not start a new session. Response code 500. 
Message: session not created: 
This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 91"
```

Code as follows:

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", new String[] { "enable-automation" });
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com/");`
```

I'm expecting to open the browser without using

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Seleniun\\sws\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Because I'm using all the below maven dependencies

```
`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>`
```

Note: If I use the System.setProperty with latest version it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you are using above dependencies it wont work because below is how selenium knows where the Chromedriver binary file is which it use for Automation execution in chrome

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","")
```

Since you are using Webdriver Manager you can add this line before your driver initialisation which will downlaod the driver binary and Internally calls  `System.setProperty` to set the chrome driver path
. Webdriver Manager will automatically download the chromedriver matching your chrome browser version

Complete code

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", new String[] { "enable-automation" });
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com/");`
```